# How can I find the camera viewplane size?

Tags: camera, resolution

I am doing plans for projects I build on our lot.  I need to submit these plans to the county and be able to use them for my contractor, too.  I'll be using a plug-in to give me the needed measurements and I've figured out how to add notes and so on.  The one other thing I'm working on is an info sheet to specify my information (as the designer and owner), address, and so on.  So an info sheet will look like a bit like this:

[image]

The white is actually alpha, although it doesn't look like it.  I've specified, in the program I use to create these sheets that the resolution is 300 DPI and the measurements are 13" x 7.5".  The camera is set for 1300 x 750 resolution.  The idea is I can prep one of these sheets, add all the other notes I need on it, save it, then import it as a plane.  It works, except for one problem.

[image]

Notice the info sheet is the same proportion as the camera, but not the same size.

It would be a big help if I could just put the info sheet flat against the camera view port, and parent them, so the image moved with the camera, that'd be great.  The problem is I can resize the image-as-a-plane to what looks like the right size, but can't be sure I get it just right until after printing it.  I had hoped the camera would have vertices I could snap the image to, but I can't do that.  And I can't get the actual size of the camera view port or position it so I can use the 3D cursor or any set of coordinates to position and size the image so it matches the camera view port.

Is there a way to either get the actual size of the camera view port, snap a plane to the view port, or size an image to the size of the view port?

I'm also open to other ideas.  The issue is this is something I'll have to do half a dozen to a dozen times on each project, so I don't want to have to make large amounts of changes to each info sheet to make it fit properly.

Comment: Hello, are you using an orthographic camera ? Then the actual distance to the camera wouldn't distort the measurements as long as it's in the view frustum. Tweak the camera orthographic size to modify the relation to world measurements

Comment: I suggest that you use the compositor to overlay the image on the finished render instead of trying to do it "in camera".

Comment: @TobiasEinarsson: Any chance you know of a good demo or write-up on that?

Comment: @Gorgious: At this point I’m not advanced enough to know for sure what kind of camera.  I just added a camera and specified the resolution size for my output image.

Comment: @Gorgious: Okay, finally had time to read about orthographic cameras.  In some shots, yes, in some shots no.

Comment: @Tango, following what we said previously, I'm now wondering why you don't want the white background?

Comment: @lemon: Maybe I could use the info sheet as a background image when I don’t need another image, in which case I could probably use the white background.  But I will probably be doing a few “context shots” for the contractor to use as reference and for the plan reviewers to see just what I’m doing.  So when I do those, I’ll be using the background images and will need transparency on the foreground image and rendered layer.

Comment: @Tango, but at the end, you want a plain color (white ?) background. So finally, is it necessary to remove the white or use alpha here? (because the blurry issue is due to this)

Comment: @lemon: Removing the white from the foreground image?  The one I'm using now, the whole background that was white was changed to alpha when I saved it from LibreOffice.  (I got help in finding out how to export it from Draw with an alpha background.)  Is that what's making it fuzzy?

Answer (score 4):

Using the compositor to do this is probably a better alternative. Something like this would do the trick:

[image: Compositor nodes]

Comment: I'm finding 2 issues with that: 1) Once I do that, the lettering gets fuzzy and has an outline, and 2) I need to adjust the size or something in the info sheet, since it clips it.  In your example, it seems to be perfect, so I'm assuming I'm doing something wrong.